# How to show related subdocument properties in Meteor

Tags: meteor

I am new to Meteor/MongoDB and I'm trying to use something like this to describe a user and his stuff in a meteor project:

```
{ _id: whatever,
  name: "John Doe",
  myToys: [ {toy_id: "truck",
             quantity: 2},
            {toy_id: "legoset",
             quantity: 4} ]
}
```

I have another collection that has all those toy_ids and their properties (manufacturer, popularity, etc. and other properties that might change later, which is why I have this in a separate collection).

How would I best code it in meteor and template it to loop through the array of toy subdocuments for a particular user and still display the associated properties of each toy?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We can Identify the logged in user with `Meteor.userId`, so if you stored that id to identify each person's toys in your toys collection so that the user can know which toys are his when using `Toys.find({})`

You could do this for your [template helper](http://docs.meteor.com/#template_call).

```
Template.home.toys = function() {
    return Toys.findOne({user:Meteor.userId});
}
```

Next you can loop through this in your template using [handlebars](http://handlebarsjs.com/)

```
<template name="home">
    Name: {{name}}
    {{#each toys.myToys}}
       Toy Id: {{toy_id}}
       Toy Quantity: {{quantity}}
    {{/each}}
</template>
```