# METEOR - Is there a mechanism for handling populations

Tags: node.js, mongodb, meteor

Mongoose (and MongoDB for that matter) seem to prefer the dbref/population idiom rather than traditional SQL relationships.

While I respect the simplicity of the solution proposed here: [How to show related subdocument properties in Meteor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15364275/how-to-show-related-subdocument-properties-in-meteor)

The MongoDB docs speak to DBRefs here:
http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/database-references/#dbref-explanation

and Mongoose Populations are documented here: http://mongoosejs.com/docs/populate.html

While pulling an item from 1 query and passing it into another query is definitely one option the syntactic sugar of being able to pull a single query that provides all of the required data in one pull has it's advantages.

What is the Meteor philosophy on this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The closest thing I know of to mongoose's populations is [collection helpers](https://github.com/dburles/meteor-collection-helpers/). It works on both the client and the server and allows you to automatically transform documents into objects with useful methods.

As you'll see in the documentation, you can use these methods to, among other things, establish relationships between documents. For example if you have `Books` and `Authors` collections you can define a helper like this:

```js
Books.helpers({
  author: function() {
    return Authors.findOne(this.authorId);
  }
});
```

Which lets your write code this:

```js
Books.findOne().author().firstName;
```

You still need to go through the effort of writing the join yourself, but once written you can use it everywhere.